# Changing movement speed when multiple keys are pressed

Tags: python, pygame, keydown

I'm trying to make a simple shooting game with a pygame, but I'm curious.
Pressing the direction key made the shape move.
Here, if you press the right direction key first and the left direction key,
how can you move to the right at a lower speed than the right direction key?
here is my origin code

```
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()       
    pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_left=1
        pos_x -=6
        if player_left==1 and pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player_left=0
            pos_x-=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a states, for the last direction key that was pressed (`last_direction_key`). Set the states in the `KEYDOWN` event (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module).
If only <kbd>LEFT</kbd> is pressed, then move to the left. If only <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is pressed, then move to the right. If both <kbd>LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is pressed, the move slowly in the direction which was not pressed last, dependent on the state of `last_direction_key`:

```py
last_direction_key = None

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                last_direction_key = event.key

    pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if last_direction_key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            pos_x += 3
        else:
            pos_x -= 3
    elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        pos_x -= 6
    elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        pos_x += 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did what you told me, and when I first pressed the right key and pressed the left key, it worked the way I wanted it to. However, when I pressed the left key more than twice with the right key still holding, it didn't work like the first time. Thank you for your answer. Could you help me one more time?

Comment: What I'm trying to build is a game where enemies come to my characters and I can shoot bullets while avoiding them. I'm going to make it possible to shoot bullets in the direction my character is looking at, and to do that, I'd like to make my character move to the right, but look to the way to the left.
I think there should be some risk to attack so safely, so I thought of a way to slow down.

Comment: I want to press the key to decide the direction to move first, and then the key to look at the direction to shoot. For example, to move slowly to the right, press the RIGHT key first, hold the RIGHT key down, and shoot enemies coming from the left.
By pressing the LEFT key, my character moves to the right, but I want to make it the direction that is looking to the left.
I always want to set the speed to normal unless I press the left or right keys at the same time.
Thank you so much for your help. If you don't understand my reply, please keep asking.

Comment: Thank you so much. ;)

Comment: It worked!!! OMG Thank you very much I will study more and try to grow!!!